# WPF event stops at toolbar panel stage

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that has a "toolbar" section at the top, and main content below that.

Intermittently (I have not been able to create a reliable set of action to reproduce the issue), buttons in the toolbar stop working for a while. The "highlight" do not appear when the mouse goes over them, and they do nothing when clicked.

The buttons are visible and seem enabled.

Here is a small snippet of the main window (I have not been able to get a reduced version to actually reproduce the bug):

```
<Window>
    <Grid Name="MainPanel">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="90"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <ToolBar Name="MainToolbar" HorizontalAlignment="Left" OverflowMode="Never">
            <Button Click="OpenWeb"/>
        </ToolBar>

        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <ToolBar>
                <Button Name="StudyListTB" Command="local:CustomCommands.ShowStudyList" Margin="5"/>

                <Button Name="StudyViewTB" Command="local:CustomCommands.ShowStudyView" Margin="5"/>

                <Button Name="ScoreViewTB" Command="local:CustomCommands.ShowStudyScore" Margin="5"/>

                <Button Name="ExportTB" Command="local:CustomCommands.CreateReport" Margin="5"/>

                <Button Name="DebugTestTB" Command="{Binding DebugTestCommand}" Margin="5"/>
            </ToolBar>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Server}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        
        <Grid>
            <!-- Main Section-->
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The issue is the same for both toolbars, the one directly in the grid and the one in the stackpanel.

I have used Snoop to find out more. When the issue happen, it seems that the "click" events stop at the "toolbar panel" stage.

[image]

This normally happen after "some use" in the main section. I have not been able to figure out a set of action that is consistent, and for the most part they don't have an effect that I can see on the toolbar. The rest of the application (everything in the main section, and the header bar to close the application) is working fine.

It also seems that some actions (not always the same) in the main data section can get it back to working. Sometimes it is something as simple as clicking a checkbox that has no action that I can find related to the toolbar.

Snoop is not giving me an answer about why the even goes no longer that the ToolBarPanel, while when the application works normally (which is most of the time) the event has no problem going all the way to the buttons.

**My question**: Any idea on how to debug what is going on? (or do you actually have an idea of what may be going on :) )

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix my issue, though I am not sure what the problem was.

The application was using a static class with **RoutedUICommand** members and creating **CommandBinding** in XAML to link to the correct functions, and then using these command bindings in the **Command** attribute of the buttons.

Changing to a MVVM way by creating **ICommand** in the ViewModel class and binding the **Command** attribute of the buttons to these commands got everything working. And the code is better! :-)